# Finish() not working for Activity in Some Devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Here is my code

```
private fun startMainActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivityTab::class.java))
    finish()
}
```

Working fine in all devices but my Samsung device. When I press the back button in the `MainActivityTab` activity, it takes me back to the previous activity.

How to make this work for all the devices?

Device: Samsung A30s

Comment: Please paste your Activity code or lines that could help

Comment: @Squti which activity code, the startActivity or the MainActivityTab activity?

Comment: Your back pressed override, click listeners, and onCreate of both activities

Comment: I don't have back pressed override, click listeners and onCreate has only business code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Intent flag like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to achieve this. Check below:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivityTab::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

**It will totally clears all previous activity(s) and start new activity**

For transition use any one from below based on your requirement:

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
```

**Or**

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
```

Comment: It is working now, but the activity starts as if it is forced, can we make it a smooth transition?

Comment: use `overridePendingTransition` after `startActivity`. Check my updated answer